# How can I show a "list" of all the showtimes of a single in multiple theaters?

Tags: mobile, small, space

There are 5 movie theaters that belong to the same company; most of them show the same movies. The number of movie theaters might increase over time (they just opened a new one already; the company builds theaters in almost every mall they find). The number of movies per day per theater isn't more than 5 (like 4-5 is a rare case; generally it's 2-3). So, I need to show the showtimes in all the theaters for today per movie. Here is a container of a movie in a list view: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVyVg.jpg (this is taken in iPhone 6plus; so, I need to take into account smaller screens also). I tried to go with the most minimalist design I can possibly go with. All the description, genre, date, trailer, reserve a seat etc will be in the DetailView. So, I want to fill that empty space with all the showtimes across all the theaters for today. I wouldn't even show the hall/room (or whatever it is called); just the times for easy seeing. Many people in where I live, go to a movie in a moment of an instant - no planning. They just check for a vacant showtime and keep rolling. In what format can I show this? Showing it in a table of 5 rows of showtimes to 5 columns of theaters (the worst case scenario) doesn't fit good in that small container and mainly the problem is the width, not the height. I have though of shrinking the name of the theater but it is just impossible; so I am thinking of doing adding a different type of control inside a table cell. What can you recommend?

You might think this question is too simple to answer but I am not a designer, so it takes more time for me to build something that would take less than 10 minutes for even an average designer.

P.S I am building this app, mainly for iOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well there is a site I use quite often which has what you are looking for (if I got your question right)
https://www.kitag.com/de/programm/jetzt-im-kino/

it's basically a cardview and scales perfectly for bigger screens

i did a short mockup so that you understand what the stuff on the site is relating to

hope this helps.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fASjsT.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: This isn't what I was looking for but I saw the two column times (which are not two columns in reality; they are separate times) and it gave me an idea. Thank you! :)